# How to use SWF height for class variable in actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash, height, class-variables

I want to use height in [SWF height=200] for class variable.

I tried the following code but it causes compile error.

```
const SWF_HEIGHT:int = 200;

package {
    import flash.display.*;

    [SWF(backgroundColor=0xffffff, width=400, height=SWF_HEIGHT)]

    public class Main extends Sprite {
        public static const Y:int = SWF_HEIGHT / 2;
    }
}
```

If I use the number, 200 instead of const SWF_HEIGHT,
the compile error doesn't happen.
But I don't want to write the same number on 2 places.

Is there way to avoid writing the same number on 2 places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- ANSWER HAS BEEN EDITED --

You need to do it the other way around:

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;

    [SWF(backgroundColor=0xffffff, width=400, height=200)]

    public class Main extends Sprite {
        private static var _swfHeight : int = -1;
        public static function get swfHeight():int{
            return _swfHeight;
        }
        public function Main():void{
            _loader = this.loaderInfo;
            _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded );
        }
        private var _loader : LoaderInfo;
        private function loaded( event : Event ) : void{
            _swfHeight = _loader.height;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a very reliable method. `stageHeight` won't always give you the height specified in the SWF metatag. It might be bigger if there are off-screen sprites, or if the stroke of a shape is slightly off-screen.

Comment: that's not true. You're talking about stage.height, not stage.stageHeight.
However, you're correct in that this isn't a correct method. I just tested different possibilities and it fails with the noScale StageScaleMode

Comment: I edited the answer to be correct. I knew I had done it somewhere, so I looked it up. This _should_ be the only really reliable solution.

Comment: @Creynders
Thanks for your answer!
Did you edit the code to get the stage height when you use noScale StageScaleMode?
If I use showAll(default mode) instead of noScale, 
can I use previous version of your code?

Comment: Yes, it should work with all stage scaling and alignment settings. Also with or without objects on or outside the stage.
If you happen to find a situation however (there's a quite a number of possible combinations) in which it doesn't work, please let me know!

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to set the height in the metatag? You could just do it in the constructor:

```
const SWF_HEIGHT:int = 200;

package {
    import flash.display.*;

    [SWF(backgroundColor=0xffffff, width=400)]

    public class Main extends Sprite {
        public static const Y:int = SWF_HEIGHT / 2;

        public function Main():void {
            height = SWF_HEIGHT;
        }
    }
}
```